Is there a way to reference the "last pull"?
If I do git reflog I can see the SHA1 reference from the last time the local branch pulled from remote. This can be handy when resolving conflicts because it lets you do a diff with main to see what changed on the remote (without your own changes distracting you).
Just wondering if there is a handy way to refer to this reference (with a @ or something) or if I'm stuck with reflog.
Something like:
git diff @lastpull main
This works fine if I look up and use the SHA1 reference in reflog instead of @lastpull. Any shortcut for this?
When I say works fine, this is when:

I'm on a feature branch
I've added commits to that feature branch
Others have added commits to remote/main after I created my feature branch
I've pulled local/main so it is up to date with the remote changes

It would graph like this:


Git refs: An overview

I'm looking to find what it labeled HEAD 2. But without having to count commits to get to it. Is there a way to refer to this last pull without numbers?

As far as I know, a pull is just a single porcelain command to perform a fetch followed by an immediate merge of what was fetched, so your question becomes "Is there a way to reference the last merge?"

@chepner merge, rebase, clone, whatever came from main before I started adding stuff

My point is, there is no special "last pull", because a pull is not a first-class "event". It's just a convenience that lets you run git pull thing instead of git fetch thing; git merge thing.

Though regarding my first comment, it might be the fetch, not the merge, that is relevant: there is a FETCH_HEAD reference that might be what you want.

@phd Does this make what I'm after clearer?

From your updated graph (and after clarifying the requirements in the chat), given have the following history:
a-b-c-d-e     < main
   \
    f-g-h     < hotfix

and you want to get commit b, you can use git merge-base e h – or git merge-base main hotfix, any commitish works – to print the hash of commit b. To then get the changes between b and hotfix (i.e. h), run git diff "$(git merge-base main hotfix)" hotfix. There's also a shorthand syntax for that: git diff main...hotfix (cf. git help diff).
Similarly, to get the changes between b and main, simply swap the arguments of the command: git diff hotfix...main or git diff "$(git merge-base hotfix main)" main. If one side is HEAD, you can leave it off: git diff HEAD...hotfix is equivalent to git diff ...hotfix ("show me the changes from the merge-base of hotfix and the current commit to hotfix itself").
This assumes that the merge-base can be determined trivially. There might be more than a single merge-base for a pair of commits.
To obtain the commit and subsequently the diff, you don't need to look at the reflog or find out the "last pull" (always remember: git pull is basically git fetch && git merge behind the scenes). The whole question can be answered by walking the history graph and computing the desired commit topologically.

You can get the latest commit's summary of a branch like
git log -n 1 develop

where develop is the branch name. If you only want the first line, then this could be useful:
git log -n 1 develop --pretty=oneline

or, if you want to have the hash only, then
git log -n 1 develop --pretty=oneline | cut -d ' ' -f1


I'm looking for something that will skip my commits. If I'm stuck looking it up I'll stick with reflog.
